# How to fetch Gmail Contacts using Google Contacts API in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I have tried [this](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html) but it does not work for me. Am I missing something? Will it still work for 2-way Google Authentication case?

Comment: Did you try the [oauth_contacts](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/oauth_contacts/) sample?

Comment: Yeah. But It did not work for me. After installing it, the icon do appear next to the address bar but does not go green. So a popup can not open up. I tried replacing the consumer key and secret, still no luck. Did it work for you?

Comment: I haven't tried it with Google Contacts but I've used the OAuth code with Twitter successfully before.